# Is it possible to create a Flash based download manager?

Tags: flash, download

I was wondering if its technologically possible to create a download manager using Adobe Flash which will have the following capabilities:

1. Providing URL to download (can be external to current website)
2. Selecting download location
3. Show downloading speed and progress
4. Use multi-thread download

Obviously the browser need to stay open for the download manager to work (unless Adobe Air is used, but that's not Flash anymore).

Will appreciate any input regarding feasibility and references.